# Text Citation with siamplain.bst

Tags: citing, text

I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{siamplain}
```

downloaded from
https://www.siam.org/journals/tex/online/siamplain.bst

How can I put text citation with `siamplain.bst` such as `\citeA` in `apacite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `siamplain` bibliography style does not appear to be able to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, be they "textual" -- e.g., "Author (2016)" -- or "parenthetic" -- e.g., "(Author, 2016)".

To generate ordinary, i.e., *numeric*, citation call-outs, just use `\cite` commands.

If you wish to use a citation management package along with the `siamplain` bibliography style, the [cite](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package probably provides all the functionality and options you may need. If you prefer to use the `natbib` citation management package, be sure to load it with the option `numbers`. I can see no reason for using the `apacite` package alongside the `siamplain` bibliography style.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc,
  author  = "Anna Author",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3001,
  volume  = 1,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = "3-4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{siamplain}
\usepackage{cite} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```